# setup Reverse lookup to get CName from IP

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I have created a CName entry in forward lookup in DNS and then created a PTR in Reverse lookup in DNS but following code always returns aliases blank.

```
IPHostEntry reverse = Dns.GetHostEntry(txtIPaddress.Text);
            Response.Write(reverse.HostName);
```

I have read somewhere that if IPv6 is enabled then aliases will be blank. So, i have disabled on both client and server machine using fixit given here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852#fixit4me

but nothing is working any help will be appreciated.

If any other way to get CName using IP ?

Comment: no. cnames cannot be reverse lookuped. PTR records map an IP to a single hostname. if you had a complete dns database available you could then take that hostname and scan the db for cname mappings, but there's no "127.0.0.1 -> my.cnamed.host" type thing available.

Comment: so, please give some more detail then how can i get CName from IP/Name of machine

Comment: you can't. cname is an alias. When you do a DNS look up on a cname, you get back a hostname, not an ip. literally in the BIND zone file you'd have something like "foobar.example.com CNAME othermachine.othersite.net". You have to do *TWO* lookups to get an IP address for the cname. foobar -> othermachine -> ip. because a single A record ("othermachine") can have **MULTIPLE** cnames pointing at it, there is no way to doing a reverse lookup to see what cname was used. not with any certainty

Comment: thanks for basic info