# python get primary domain name from ip

Tags: python, dns, ip

I need to get primary domain name from ip. I have some doubts about how functions like [gethostbyaddr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr) and [getfqdn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn) work.

In the following example I'm going to reverse ip a random domain and then try to get the domain name back:

```py
import socket

domain = 'heroku.com'

# get ip from domain
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
print('ip =', ip)

# get domain from ip
print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip))
print(socket.getfqdn(ip))

# OUTPUT
# ip = 50.19.85.154
# ('ec2-50-19-85-154.compute-1.amazonaws.com', ['154.85.19.50.in-addr.arpa'], ['50.19.85.154'])
# ec2-50-19-85-154.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

It seems both `gethostbyaddr` and `getfqdn` are returning the public DNS of one of the load balanced ec2 on AWS. My question is why they don't return the domain `heroku.com` which is probably the domain registered on Route53?

Another example with `google.com`:

```py
import socket

domain = 'google.com'

# get ip from domain
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
print('ip =', ip)

# get domain from ip
print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip))
print(socket.getfqdn(ip))

# OUTPUT
# ip = 216.58.208.174
# ('mil07s10-in-f14.1e100.net', ['174.208.58.216.in-addr.arpa', 'lhr25s09-in-f14.1e100.net', 'lhr25s09-in-f174.1e100.net'], ['216.58.208.174'])
# mil07s10-in-f14.1e100.net
```

Here again it seems they are returning the public DNS of some machine on GCP. How can I get the real primary domain name from an ip address (`heroku.com` and `google.com` in these examples)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547328/setup-reverse-lookup-to-get-cname-from-ip. Refer to the comments of this question. It seems reverse DNS lookup for CNAME records is not possible

Comment: @MohithReddy "reverse DNS lookup for CNAME records" does not mean anything. A reverse lookup uses a `PTR` record. This goes from an IP encoded in a specific domain name to another domain name. When you have a chain of CNAME, at the end you expect an `A` or `AAAA` record if that was the query. That record may have a `PTR` record then for the reverse query.

Comment: You seem to believe that all reverse queries should work. There is no guarantee about that and no necessity either: any IP address could have a `PTR` record but in practice either do not have one or have one giving you back a name different from the one you started with. Think about mass virtual HTTP/HTTPS hosting: multiple names resolve to the same IP address. You can not expect (while technically it is possible) that a reverse lookup on the IP would yield back absolutely all names hosted on that IP

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Reverse DNS queries can only be performed with IP address. By the line "It seems reverse DNS lookup for CNAME records is not possible", I meant the same there is no such procedure like that.

Comment: In case of virtual hosting, I believe the ``PTR`` record (if configured) is configured in such a way that it returns the hosting node name (if it has one) instead of the virtual hosts it is hosting.Is it not the case ?

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanations. So in practice there is no guarantee that such lookup is feasible and the only way to go is to retrieve WHOIS data from the ip and see if it is possible to extract the domain from there. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is only the way.

Answer (score 1):

When we do a DNS lookup of a hostname, in the most of the cases we are returned with the `CNAME`. We take that `CNAME`, and further resolve it to get an IP. But multiple `CNAME`'s in the (n-1)th stage can be mapped to the `CNAME` in the (n)th stage. Therefore getting back the `CNAME` from the `CNAME` of the later stages is a not a trivial task.

#### Another Possible Way

Well, now the discussion is moving away from the DNS, but I hope it helps you. Every router or node in the internet is mapped to a Autonomous System, and there are some organizations or sites which maintain this mapping database. So by having the IP, we can contact one such database to get its Autonomous System Number (ASN) and the organization to which the node belongs to. `whois.cymru.com:43` is one such site. You can use simple network client like `nc` to query its database. Below I attached the screenshot of one such query.

[image]

Comment: "When we do a DNS lookup of a hostname, in the most of the cases we are returned with the CNAME.". No. If you use a recursive nameserver it will ask recursively, even if they are multiple CNAME until it gets the final result which it will present to you. Or an error.

Comment: Any proper `whois` client can do such queries, you do not need `nc`. You can query RIRs for IP addresses and AS numbers.

Comment: Yes, but lets not talk about the recursive and iterative DNS queries. To see what happens under the hood consider iterative queries. Moreover, even in recursive queries, this same iteration is performed by another node on our behalf

Comment: Well regarding RIR, my knowledge ends there. I will definitely do some reading and learn about it. Thanks !